# Tracking traffic sources across domain redirect

Tags: dns, google-analytics, cross-domain, analytics, tracking

I have a domain *AAAA.com* which is used for marketing an App. It redirects to a page on another domain: BBBB.com/buy-app.php, where Google Analytics is set up.

How do I on *BBBB.com/buy-app.php* track where the traffic is coming from?

---

E.g:

An users clicks on a link to *AAAA.com* on Facebook, which redirects to *BBBB.com/buy-app.php* – how do I the know where the user came from?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about "Tracking Multiple Domains": [Google Analytics for Developers: Tracking Multiple Domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite)

For this same use case, I prefer to use Google Analytics on Steroids: [Google Analytics on Steroids: Cross Domain Tracking](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas#cross-domain)

```
_gas.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1']);
_gas.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gas.push(['_setDomainName', 'AAAA.com']);
_gas.push(['_setDomainName', 'BBBB.com']);
_gas.push(['_gasMultiDomain', 'mousedown']);
```

* *Note*: calling `_setDomainName` multiple times is only supported in `_gas` and not supported by the default `_gaq`.

Comment: Thanks man, I will take a look at it - and hopefully mark it as an answer when I get it working.

So.. I will simply replace my _gaq code with _gas? and do as you suggests above?

Comment: Yes, the documentation for conversion is very good on [GAS's README](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas)

Comment: I've installed GAS on the BBB.com domain. But the thing is that an user will click on a link to AAA.com which should instantly (301 ??) redirect to our main BBB.com domain.

How do I track on the AAA.com domain and then instantly redirect? 

The AAA.com domain's only purpose is to redirect - it has no content.

I imagine using .htaccess or a php redirect somehow.

Comment: If it's 301, the referral information is usually passed along.  In the case of your e.g. above you will see Facebook sending the traffic on BBBB.com's GA account

Comment: I got it working using a 302 redirect using .htaccess - thanks!